# How to get details from a Google Maps location?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I use `GeoLocation` to get the current position from an user when they visit my webpage. But I want to get the details of that coordinates `GeoLocation` gives me.

I mean, if the api gives me two specific locations, I want to gather the address, zip code, city, county, country (if they're able to) etc... Is there a way to do that?

Thank you all!

Comment: [Reverse geocoding: The term geocoding generally refers to translating a human-readable address into a location on a map. The process of doing the converse, translating a location on the map into a human-readable address, is known as reverse geocoding.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)

Comment: @geocodezip hey, add your comment as answer so I can mark this as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reverse geocoding (from the documentation): The term geocoding generally refers to translating a human-readable address into a location on a map. The process of doing the converse, translating a location on the map into a human-readable address, is known as reverse geocoding.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)